# How to validate the opportunity name by using the Regex method in Salesforce Validation

Tags: validation

I wanna check the field value should be the title case. how to write the Salesforce validation rule for this.

It should be allow the special char and symbol.

I have used the below code: but it shows syntax error.

```
NOT(REGEX(Name, "([A-Z](\w*[\W\s]+))+"))
```

Comment: I don't think I totally understand what you're trying to match. What are the characters or cases that you want to exclude?

Comment: The opp name should be the title case. thats why am wrote the validation rule

Comment: What do you mean by "title case"? Are you saying you want the Opp Name to begin with a capital letter and from your examples, anything that follows a period, ampersand, parens, hyphen and perhaps other symbols should be capitalized as well?? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

The validation rule formula you want is:

```
REGEX(Name, ".*\\b(?<!')\\p{Ll}.*" )
```

Note that a validation rule formula should return **true** when there is an error; translating this to your use case, we need a formula to return true when the opportunity name contains a word that starts with a lowercase letter.  Note that "A word that starts with..." could be rephrased as "a word boundary followed by..."; "word boundary" is a regex concept meaning the boundary between a word and anything that is not a word (whitespace, punctuation, etc.).

**Update**: as pointed out in comments, this fails for words with apostrophes, like "Facebook's & Co."  This is because `\b` matches a word boundary, which is the space between a "word character" and a "non-word character", and apostrophe is considered a non-word character.  Since we can't re-define `\b`, we need to just ensure that we don't match word boundaries immediately following an apostrophe.  We can do this with a zero-width negative look-behind assertion, which looks behind itself and asserts that something doesn't appear in the text.  I've updated the regex above to include this test.

`REGEX(text, regex_text)` returns true if `regex_text` matches `text`.  It is **important to note** that, per [the documentation for the `REGEX()` function](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#REGEXSection), the function only returns true if the regex matches the **entire** `text` string, and that backslash, being an escape character in Salesforce strings, must itself be escaped with another backslash (i.e., doubled).

Therefore, the regex works as follows:

```
.*       // match any number of characters
\\b      // escaped \b, means "word boundary"
(?<!')   // fail if the character just before the word boundary is '
\\p{Ll}  // escaped \p{Ll}, matches any unicode lowercase value
.*       // match any number of characters.
```

The leading and trailing `.*` allow us to match the entire opportunity name, if the `\\b(?<!')\\p{Ll}` matches and word boundary that is not preceeded by `'` and is followed by a lowercase letter.

So this rule will throw an error for "Facebook Corp. & **co**", but not for "Facebook Corp. & **Co**".

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution i marked as the best answer. I am still have the issue. if i type Facebook's Company. I got error. but it should allow the special symbol.

Comment: What is the exact string that is generating the error?  I tested this formula in a DE org using "Facebook Corp. & Co." and it worked.

Comment: Customer may enter like this : Facebook's Corp. & Co. so it should be allow. apostrophe

Comment: Are you able to understand my query? Can you help to resolve this please.

Comment: Can you help if you can or let me know.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I updated my answer this morning to address the apostrophe, I just forgot to add a comment here.  Please try the updated solution.

Comment: I want to update the prior records as well. So how to query the record which are the record not being the title case. I want to export and rename that account. But I dont know how to get that record.

Comment: @Alex Please open a new question for your prior records.  Questions should be limited to a single topic.

Comment: Wwhen i entered  FACEBOOK CORP. It is showing error. as per my request first letter only capitalize

Comment: @JasonClark Why your code allows all caps. it should not allow know? please can you change?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, my solution really only requires each word in company name to be capitalized, and doesn't look at rest of word.  What about companies that use all capitals, such as IBM?

Comment: @JasonClark Yes. if we enter IBM, it should be throw error. and also if we enter IBm as well.

Comment: @JasonClark please look this, i have created new question for you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81495/opportunity-name-validaiton-by-using-the-regex-method-in-validation-rule

Comment: @JasonClark Are you there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
REGEX(Name, ".*\\b\\p{Ll}.*" )
```

Answer (score 0):

simple one
hope this will work for u.

[link](https://regex101.com/r/nV6tL2/1)

This regex

expression u can use.

"/\p{Lu}/g" in regex method.

Comment: How to use this in validation rule

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava can you tell me where are all the guidelines reside for salefroce.stackexchange.
everyone either devote my answer or put suggestion.

Comment: @Ankuli It is easy to get to this kind of feeling .Only reason i commented was link won't help user .Please keep contributing to this site .There is no concept of senior or junior here .If answer deserves upvote I make sure I upvote .If it has some flaws I make sure I maintain good quality  of content ,Check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Ankuli Everyone here is to help others get solution to problems .There is no personal growth as you don't get paid here .Also there us no jealous concept please .This answer was unclear please .keep energy high and keep contributing .

Comment: Hey Ankuli, you might find this section of the help area useful to read: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

You would have been downvoted originally because link-only answers are generally not accepted here: links can break over time and that renders the answer useless. It's far better to include relevant content from the linked page so that the answer can stand on it's own should the link fail in the future.

There's nothing personal about downvotes, it's just how the site maintains a high level of quality content. As Mohith says, please keep contributing!