# Opportunity name validaiton by using the Regex method in Validation rule

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I have used the below code for check the field value should be the title case. it is working fine but when I entering capital letter for all text, it is not throwing the error. but it should through.

My Code:
i have used the below link code

FYI : [How to validate the opportunity name by using the Regex method in Salesforce Validation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72675/how-to-validate-the-opportunity-name-by-using-the-regex-method-in-salesforce-val/72707#72707)

e.g : when i enter the FACEBOOK, It should not allow. it should be Facebook.

Comment: since the link you posted has multiple regex answers - post the one you are using here.  I presume you have tried it with an online regex tester